# What is the significance of 世界 in all the Go tutorials?

Tags: go

In many of the Go tutorials ([A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1), [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)) and even the [main golang.org](https://golang.org/)'s page 'try it' the Chinese characters for 'World', `世界`, are used in place of 'Hello World'.

What is the reason for this?

Go was developed by Google and lists a [worldwide collection of contributers](https://golang.org/CONTRIBUTORS), so not being particularly English (or US)-centric isn't surprising. But I can't find anything in the documentation or history that points to why this is.

Maybe I'm just imagining a quirk?

Comment: I suppose it is to show that their strings can handle unicode?...

Comment: If you watch the video it is explained. It's Japanese, and it is meant to show that Go's code is UTF-8 compatible out of the box.

Comment: It's both Japanese and Chinese, as a Unicode demonstration. During the time when the document was written (and even now), many language including Python struggles in dealing non-ascii characters.

Comment: You can also do: `世界 := "Hello"` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a quick, and effective, way of demonstrating that Go supports unicode.

Comment: I'm also impressed that a basic type is 'rune', explicitly for Unicode code points. Seems to fit with this explanation.